# HTML <code> - get rid of newlines

Tags: html, css

How can I get the `<code>` tag not to have newlines before and after? I have tried `<span>` to no success. I also tried a nested `<p>` with in the `li` to no success.

I don't think it matters, but just for the record I am also using prism.js for code styling.

For example, I want this to be all in on line:

```
 <ul>
                <li>great way to replace a infinite loop such as <code id = "loopSnippet" class="language-javascript">while (true) { .. }</code></li>
```

Instead, the `while (true) { .. }` has it's own line underneath.

Here is a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Lx2bzvhm/

Comment: The problem is caused by code that is not present in the question. Fiddles are tools to help working on a problem, *not* a replacement for a problem description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `display: inline-block` instead of `block` on your `<code>`

http://jsfiddle.net/Lx2bzvhm/4/

Answer (score 3):

The CSS declares `code { display: block; }`. Remove that declaration of `display: block;` or change it to `display: inline;` or `display: inline-block;`, whichever is more appropriate for your situation.

Comment: Yep, here's a [revised jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lx2bzvhm/5/) that does that.

Answer (score 1):

[check here](http://jsfiddle.net/Lx2bzvhm/1/)

use  `display: inline-block` [check out the link for inline-block](http://learnlayout.com/inline-block.html)